# Cannot connect to local SQL Server with Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, localhost

I'm having an issue with SQL Server, I have 2005 installed on my desktop as well as having SQL Server Management Studio installed..

I've checked and can see "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" started in services.

I've tried to connect to "Local" and "SQLEXPRESS" but both fail to connect.

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to     SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)

Anything else I need to do to connect to it??

---

### UPDATE

I seem to be getting a little further along now. Ive managed to connect to my server with SQL Server Management (FYI .\SQLEXPRESS did the trick)  but now im having a issue with my connection string in my web.config

Ive im going to connect to this local sql server using windows authentication how do i need to structure it??

Something like this?

```
<add name="BensBoxing" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BritBoxing_Alpha;Integrated Security=False;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This produces a error about

Login failed for user ''.

Comment: try `.\SQLEXRPESS` for S&Gs.

Comment: Have you tried `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: Can you post your connection string from the web.config?  Is it in the same PC as the database?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check the sql log in the LOG directory of your instance - see if anything is going on there.  You'll need to stop the service to open the log - or restart and you can read the old one - named with .1 on the end.

With the error you're getting, you need to enable TCP/IP or Named pipes for named connections.  Shared memory connection should work, but you seem to not be using that.  Are you trying to connect through SSMS?

In my log I see entries like this...

```
Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [\\.\pipe\mssql$sqlexpress\sql\query ]
```

As the comments said, .\SQLEXPRESS should work.  Also worstationName\SQLEXPRESS will work.

Comment: this has helped alot but im still having troubles with connecting with web.config now!!

Comment: Very helpful! this exactly fixed my problem connect to SQL Express with SQL-MS. Thanks a ton for the post.

Answer (score 30):

Same as [matt said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9876669/901048). The "SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)" was stopped. Enabled it by opening Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services, right-clicking on the "SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)" service and selecting "Start" from the available options.
Could connect fine after that.

Comment: for me it was `SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)`

Comment: @David, I don't find it in my services. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

I was having this problem on a Windows 7 (64 bit) after a power outage. The SQLEXPRESS service was not started even though is status was set to 'Automatic' and the mahine had been rebooted several times. Had to start the service manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see, if the service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" it's started, this solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks - that actually fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open Sql server 2014 Configuration Manager.

Click Sql server services and start the sql server service if it is stopped

Then click Check SQL server Network Configuration for TCP/IP Enabled

then restart the sql server management studio (SSMS)
and connect your local database engine